# Можно ли любить беззвучно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, стилистическая-сочетаемость

"Любить беззвучно" или "любить безмолвно"?

Comment: Благодарю давших ответы!, но, к моему сожалению, я так и не понял как правильно, поскольку ответы противоречивы.

Comment: лучше беззвучно, потому что может мешать соседям

Answer (score 3):

> Я Вас любил безмолвно, безнадежно,
>
> То робостью, то ревностью томим;
>
> Я Вас любил так искренно, так нежно,
>
> Как дай Вам Бог любимой быть другим.

"Безмолвная любовь" — это реминисценция, отсылка к вышеупомянутому стихотворению А.С. Пушкина. Если Вы хотите показать, что знакомы с русской классической традицией, говорите именно так.

"Беззвучная любовь" — это, скорее всего, аберрация данного выражения. Так обычно бывает, когда человек не слишком осведомлен, но хочет произвести впечатление. Но если абстрагироваться от традиции, исходить исключительно из значений слов, то у этих выражений есть существенная семантическая разница, которую уже объяснили другие эксперты.

Answer (score 1):

Беззвучно — не издавая звуков, безмолвно — не промолвив и слова. Первое к любви не относится и в сочетании со словом *любить* режет слух.

"Беззвучно" - так говорят о действии, которое могло бы сопровождаться звуками. Пример корректного употребления слова *беззвучно*:

> ― Ах, я люблю, я люблю, ― **беззвучно шепчет** Таня. [Р. И. Фраерман. Дикая собака Динго, или Повесть о первой любви (1935-1940)]

Answer (score 0):

Конечно. Также, как и молча, и тихо, то есть, не выражая звуком внешне своих чувств. " Я безмолвно тебе говорю о любви! Ты, как солнце в ночи, - где-то есть, но не здесь... Этот миг я тебе посвящаю. Но, услышав мой зов, молчи: сердцу благость побыть в печали.

Answer (score 0):

Сравним словарные значения слов ***безмолвно*** и ***беззвучно***.

БЕЗМОЛВНЫЙ, 1. Не говорящий, молчащий; молчаливый. Б. свидетель. * Бродил безмолвен, одинок (Лермонтов). // **Не сопровождаемый, не выраженный словами.** Б. укор, вопрос. Б-ая поддержка. Б-ое участье к кому-л. 2. **Не оглашаемый звуками; хранящий тишину**. Б-ая степь. Б-ая деревня. Ночь тепла и безмолвна. <Безмолвно, нареч.

БЕЗЗВУЧНЫЙ, **Лишённый звуков; не издающий их; едва слышный.** Б-ая ночь. Б. смех. Б-ые рыдания. Б-ые шаги. <Беззвучно, нареч. Подойти б. Б. плакать.

Отсюда следует, что существует **безмолвная любовь** (не выраженная словами), а ***беззвучной любви*** в прямом (или обычном) смысле нет.

Но это в прямом смысле, а в переносном значении это выражение может звучать как свежая **метафора**, находка поэта.

Answer (score 0):

Из словаря Ефремовой:
[беззвучный](https://%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2.%D1%80%D1%84/wd/%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9), прил.
I. Не издающий звуков (об органах речи).
II. 1. Лишенный звуков, не сопровождаемый звуками.
2. Лишенный звучности; глухой.
3. Неслышный.

Мне кажется, что говорить *любить беззвучно* вполне допустимо.
Немое кино, космическое пространство, люди, которые не говорят или не слышат, живые существа под водой, фотографии... Особенное, удивительное, всегда неповторимое чувство сопровождается особенными словами. Но иногда — только взгляд, полный беззвучной любви.

*Когда ж любовь стремится к выраженью,

Её язык — беззвучная тирада.*
Е. Белова

*Все было как в немом кино: где сердца стук почти не слышен;

Где жест важнее, чем слова; где нежность все еще жива…

Моя [**беззвучная любовь**](http://testicanzoni.mtv.it/testi-Jamala_13930647/testo-%D0%A3-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D0%A2%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8-%D0%93%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0-19112490), последний ряд, и запах вишен,

И ты — все было, как в кино…*

*И говорить о любви бессмысленно, поэтому в моем фильме она беззвучна. Любовь — это то, какими друг друга видят влюбленные. Это величайшая тайна, и словами ее не выразить* (из интервью с режиссером «Формы воды» Гильермо дель Торо).

*Порой беззвучны наши чувства,

Боясь спугнуть, едва дыша...

Понять друг друга — верх искусства.

Прильнули мы к душе душа.*
Л. Иовлев

Answer (score 0):

Приставка "без-". Она говорит о том, что само действие вовсе не исключено, оно есть, но не по тому поводу, который обозначен словом. То есть: "беззвучная любовь" - звуки-то есть, но они не выказывают выражения любви; "безмолвная любовь" - слова какие-то есть, произносятся, но они не выражают признаний в любви.